# rails 4 Paperclip: undefined method `brand_logo_image_content_type' for #<Batch:0x431a408>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to migrate rails app project from version 3 to rails version 4.0.0 . I am trying to save an image using paperclip gem of version(4.2.1) but getting below error

```
undefined method `brand_logo_image_content_type' for #<Batch:0x431a408>
```

below is my model

```
class Batch < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :brand_logo_image, :styles => {:thumb => "16x16>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :brand_logo_image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates_attachment_presence :brand_logo_image
  validates_attachment_size :brand_logo_image, :less_than => 1.megabytes, :unless => Proc.new {|m| m[:brand_logo_image].nil?}
end
```

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have created the associated migration ? `rails paperclip Batch brand_logo_image && rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game, but for posterity: You probably haven't added the necessary columns in the migration.

Makes sure you have in change

```
add_attachment :batch, :brand_logo_image
```

or in up

```
change_table :batch do |t|
  t.attachment :brand_logo_image
end
```

which should create the appropriate columns in the table:

```
batch_file_name
batch_file_size
batch_content_type
batch_updated_at
```